# Uninitialized constant Rails when i tried to run Rails.cache.clear in capistrano task when deployed to vps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I tried to run

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

by Capistrano task when i deploy my app to the server.
This is my code

```
namespace :deploy do
    desc 'Clear memcache'
    task :clear_memcache do
      on roles(:app) , in: :sequence, wait: 2 do
        Rails.cache.clear
        CACHE.flush
      end
    end

    before :starting,     :check_revision
    after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
    after  :finishing,    :cleanup
    after  :finishing,    :copy_missing_css
    after  :finishing,    :clear_cache
    after  :finishing,    :clear_memcache
    after  :finishing,    :restart
end
```

But i got this error.

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<NameError: uninitialized constant Rails>
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try ::Rails for an absolute reference to this module or maybe you need to use a require 'rails' to fix this.

Comment: How can i use ::Rails?

Comment: This is an absolute reference to Rails module.

Comment: after i change to this task :clear_memcache => :environment do
    on roles(:app) , in: :sequence, wait: 2 do
      ::Rails.cache.clear
      CACHE.flush
    end
  end

It said
Don't know how to build task 'environment'

Any idea?

Comment: Have you used require 'rails' in the beginning of your task?

Comment: yes but still got <RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'environment'

Comment: Then may be something related to capistrano, and I'm not used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Capistrano  tasks are not a rails app - within them `Rails` does not exist. Even if it did, this is code executing on the machine doing the deploy, not your servers (and memcached should not be externally available)

What you want is to run something on the server, which you do with `execute` method, or via helpers such as `runner` or `rake` that call execute for you. This uses `bin/rails runner` to execute the code

```
within release_path do
  with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
    runner "Rails.cache.clear"
  end
end
```

You could also create a rake task and invoke that via `execute`. As an aside you only need to run this once - it doesn't need to be repeated on all servers.